# How to solve this problem 710 of Project-Euler

Tags: combinatorics, memory, project-euler

I want to solve [this problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=710):

> The number 6 can be written as a palindromic sum in exactly eight different ways:
>
> (1,1,1,1,1,1),(1,1,2,1,1),(1,2,2,1),(1,4,1),(2,1,1,2),(2,2,2),(3,3),(6)
> We shall define a twopal to be a palindromic tuple having at least one element with a value of 2. It >should also be noted that elements are not restricted to single digits. For example, (3,2,13,6,13,2,3) >is a valid twopal.
>
> If we let t(n) be the number of twopals whose elements sum to n, then it can be seen that t(6)=4:
>
> (1,1,2,1,1),(1,2,2,1),(2,1,1,2),(2,2,2)
> Similarly, t(20)=824.
>
> In searching for the answer to the ultimate question of life, the universe, and everything, it can be >verified that t(42)=1999923, which happens to be the first value of t(n) that exceeds one million.
>
> However, your challenge to the "ultimatest" question of life, the universe, and everything is to find the least value of n>42 such that t(n) is divisible by one million.

I quickly got the value of t(20) using the following method:

```
   Count[(Flatten[Permutations /@ Evaluate[IntegerPartitions[20, All]], 
        1]) // DeleteDuplicates, u_ /; u == Reverse[u] && MemberQ[u, 2]]
```

However, when I use the above method to solve t(42), I am prompted that the memory is insufficient. How can I avoid memory overflow errors?

Comment: By not generating all permutations. These Project-Euler problems are _designed_ so that direct brute-force approach does not work.

Comment: You can get a smaller set of candidates before using `Permutations`. For  example, `(Select[Not[FreeQ[2]@#] && Count[Tally[#][[All, 2]], _?OddQ] <= 1 &]@
  IntegerPartitions[20, All])`

Comment: Note that except for the first few problems, PE problems are intentionally infeasible by a brute force approach. You usually have to rethink the problem mathematically first, to have it in a form that is computationally manageable. Here you are essentially asking that someone does this work for you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***"when I use the above method to solve t(42), I am prompted that the memory is insufficient. How can I avoid memory overflow errors?"***

```
ClearAll[twoPalCount]
twoPalCount = Total @* 
 Map[Multinomial @@ Floor[Values[Counts@#]/2] &] @*
 Select[Not[FreeQ[2]@#] && Count[Tally[#][[All, 2]], _?OddQ] <= 1 &] @*
 IntegerPartitions;


{#, twoPalCount@#} & /@ Range[42] // Grid
```

[image]

**See:** [Number of palindromic permutations](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/number-of-palindromic-permutations-set-1/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The efficiency of your code has been improved a lot. But the question requires that the result can be divisible by one million. This number is too large, and the code still needs further improvement.

Comment: @PleaseCorrectGrammarMistakes,  you might want to  add the part  "the question requires that the result can be divisible by one million" to your question from the link you provided.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Reprint the answer of MuthuVeerappanR in [the forum of Project-Euler](https://projecteuler.net/thread=710#last).

> The generating function of palindromic compositions with u marking the number of 2's is given by
>
> $$\displaystyle P(z,u)=\sum_{n,k}p(n)z^nu^k=\frac{1+x+ux^2+x^3+x^4+\cdots}{1-x^2-u^2x^4-x^6-x^8-\cdots}=\frac{(u-1)x^2+(1-x)^{-1}}{2-(u^2-1)x^4-(1-x^2)^{-1}}$$
>
> This gives, $\displaystyle T(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty t(n)z^n=P(z,1)-P(z,0)=\frac{z^2(1-z^2)}{1-3z^2-z^3+2z^4+2z^5}$.
>
> From this we get the linear recursion that solves the problem.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
ans = {};
Do[
  res = SeriesCoefficient[(1 + x + y x^2 + 
       Sum[Power[x, k], {k, 3, j}])/(1 - x^2 - y^2 x^4 - 
       Sum[Power[x, k], {k, 6, j, 2}]), {x, 0, j}];
  res = (res /. y -> 1) - (res /. y -> 0);
  ans = Join[ans, {res}];
  , {j, 0, 20}];
FindGeneratingFunction[ans, z]
ans
p1 = 2; p2 = 0; p3 = 1; p4 = 0; p5 = 0; c = 5;
Monitor[While[True,
    temp = Mod[3 p2 + p3 - 2 p4 - 2 p5, 1000000];
    {p1, p2, p3, p4, p5} = {temp, p1, p2, p3, p4};
    If[temp == 0, Break[];];
    c += 1;
    ];, c];
c
CoefficientList[
  PolynomialMod[Power[z, 42], 
   Power[z, 5] - 3 Power[z, 3] - Power[z, 2] + 2 Power[z, 1] + 2], 
  z].{0, 0, 1, 0, 2}
```